# Get values in Dataframe based on another vector

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `asd`. I need to get values in column b based on matching values in another vector

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c("a","b", "c"), b = c(1,3,4), c = c("g", "f", "h"))
sel_val <- c("a", "c")
asd$b[asd$a == sel_val]
[1] 1
Warning message:
In asd$a == sel_val :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Expected output

```
[1] 1 4
```

Comment: Use `asd$b[asd$a %in% sel_val]`

Answer (score 2):

You will want to match what values of `asd$a` are in `sel_val`:

```
asd[asd$a %in% sel_val,]$b
```